# Is it possible to host 200+ websites on an Azure VM

Tags: azure

I am doing some preliminary research on Windows Azure. The idea is to move 200+ ASP classic websites to Windows Azure. I am wondering if this is possible and feasible? Can I host that many websites on a single VM? Also note that each website needs to have its own set of email addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's absolutely no reason why you couldn't host all those sites on Azure VM (assuming you're talking about the preview Virtual Machine functionality).  You get your own isolated machine, with its own IIS and IP.  What you put on it is up to you, but it's no different than getting a VPS from any other company (rackspace etc.).

Obviously this is assuming that your sites are not very resource heavy and the memory etc. you get with different VM sizes can support the use.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right answer but it is reassuring. (I'll appreciate any references or pointers to case studies regarding setting up IIS on Azure for virtual hosting).

Comment: It's going to be hard to get any case studies seeing how VM is still in preview and very recently released (early June).  Personally I would not use it for anything production-related, nor would I recommend it as production ready to my clients.  Really all you can find now is marketing material from MS and Azure documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Marek's answer isn't wrong, but please don't use "Virtual Machines" for this, and instead use Cloud Services (specifically, a web role). A web role lets you deploy just your code (in this case: websites) without having to mess with managing a full VM.

In short, PaaS is better than IaaS, as long as your app fits the model (which IIS-based websites do in Windows Azure).

I don't know what "each website needs to have its own set of email addresses" means or how it relates.

Comment: A choice between using a web role or a full VM should really be made on a case by case basis and there's hardly enough information to determine which one is appropriate in this case.  Especially if you take security isolation under consideration http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433110.aspx.  But overall I'd agree - I would try to fit my sites into a web role instead of a VM just to avoid any maintenance overhead (and easier scaling).

Comment: Cost can also be a big factor. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PennyPinchingInTheCloudWhenDoAzureWebsitesMakeSense.aspx